# Why the getter in SwiftUI does not need to use return keyword even if there are more than one line?

Tags: swift, swiftui, return, getter

Can you help me understand the below code from Apple's SwiftUI tutorial?
I think the "**body**" variable is a computed property with a getter.

As per my understanding, you must use **return** keyword to return a value if there are more than one lines in the getter. How come the below code can be compiled without issue?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LandmarksApp: App {
    @StateObject private var modelData = ModelData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        let mainWindow = WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(modelData)
        }
        
        #if os(macOS)
        mainWindow.commands { LandmarkCommands() }
        #else
        mainWindow
        #endif

        #if os(watchOS)
        WKNotificationScene(controller: NotificationController.self, category: "LandmarkNear")
        #endif

        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            LandmarkSettings()
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Umh, there's different points to answers here.

I think you will find a lots of details answers to swift ui body/content builder overs here: [John Sundell - features that power SwiftUI’s API](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-swift-51-features-that-power-swiftuis-api/)

For a quick explanation, there's two behaviour at play:

- Type Inference
- Sugar Synthax / Language Added to SwiftUI w/ `functionBuilder` or others

### Type Inference

> Swift is a statically typed language, meaning that the type of every property, constant and variable that we declare needs to be specified at compile time. However, that’s often not something that needs to be done manually, instead the compiler is able to figure out a wide range of type information on its own — thanks to the fact that Swift supports type inference. [John Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/type-inference/)

### Sugar Synthax / Functions Builders

New language solution added by apple, that extend the compiler using generics and others tricks.